# facebook-scraper in python not working for all public profiles/pages

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

The following script works for only the first page i.e. 'EvanCarmichaelcom' and not for the rest even though they are also public and have public posts

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

pageList = ['EvanCarmichaelcom','terrywadethompson','evan.tinstman']

for pageName in pageList:
    print(pageName)
    for post in get_posts(pageName,pages=2):

       postentry = post

       print(postentry)
```

For the 'evan.tinstman' profile, it requires credentials but when I pass them to the get_posts() function, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 44-46: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them? So don't be surprised when you get banned.

Comment: @WizKid I am only going to run this script once every 3 days to get their latest post, that's it, don't think it'll get noticed